# Firebase with Google API - Billing and/or Authentication Required

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions

### Goal

Use [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) in a Firebase Cloud Function using the [free Firebase Spark plan.](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

### Context

I have deployed the cloud functions code below to my Firebase project. The helloWorld endpoint works as expected.

The urlShortener endpoint returns two errors:

```
Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup...
```

and

```
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
```

### Question

If I send an authenticated request [as demonstrated here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint), will this solve both errors?

Or, is googleapis somehow considered an `External network` and both errors must be addressed, e.g., turn on billing to use googleapis?

### Code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const googleapis = require('googleapis');
const googleauth = require('google-auth-library');
var urlshortener = googleapis.urlshortener('v1');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

var params = {
    shortUrl: 'short.url' //fake url for this comment
};

// get the long url of a shortened url
exports.urlShortener = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    urlshortener.url.get(params, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Encountered error', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Long url is', response.longUrl);
          response.send("LongURL: ", response.longUrl);
        }
      });          
});
```

Comment: I think this error was about Google Cloud Platform billing and not Firebase billing. I have turned on billing for both, and I no longer get the error.